# Handle dynamic staticfiles path with Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm almost overcoming to finish my `Theme Selector` with `Django` but I'm blocking on one point :

==> I don't arrive to get a dynamic staticfiles path according to the form result given by user.

I will explain the process :

User fills a Django form by checking a RadioSelect box. He has a choice between two options :

- **Datasystems**
- **Cameroun**

Both options correspond to 2 themes which have two differents background-colors. **Datasystems** is blue & white and **Cameroun** is green & red.

So, I pick up the form result corresponding to one of both theme which are situated in static files :

```
|--- app1
|--- app2
├── static
│   └── Theme
│       ├── Cameroun
│       │   ├── css
│       │   │   ├── Base.css
│       │   │   ├── Base_Accueil.css
│       │   │   ├── Base_Birthcertificate.css
│       │   │   ├── Base_Configurations.css
│       │   │   ├── Base_Identity.css
│       │   │   ├── Base_Mairie.css
│       │   │   ├── Base_Recensement.css
│       │   │   └── Base_Table.css
│       │   └── images
│       │       ├── admin.png
│       │       ├── chantier.jpeg
│       │       ├── chantier.png
│       │       ├── employe?\201.png
│       │       ├── logo.png
│       │       ├── maire.png
│       │       ├── officier.png
│       │       ├── stats.jpeg
│       │       └── visiteur.png
│       └── Datasystems
│           ├── css
│           │   ├── Base.css
│           │   ├── Base_Accueil.css
│           │   ├── Base_Birthcertificate.css
│           │   ├── Base_Configurations.css
│           │   ├── Base_Identity.css
│           │   ├── Base_Mairie.css
│           │   ├── Base_Recensement.css
│           │   └── Base_Table.css
│           └── images
│               ├── admin.png
│               ├── chantier.jpeg
│               ├── chantier.png
│               ├── employe?\201.png
│               ├── logo.png
│               ├── maire.png
│               ├── officier.png
│               ├── stats.jpeg
│               └── visiteur.png
```

In my settings.py file, I have the static path like this :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "/Etat_civil/static/Theme/"),)
```

I'm using templates_tag but I'm not sure if my function could be write like this :

```
from django import template
from Configurations.models import Theme

register = template.Library() 

def GetTheme(Theme):

    mytheme = Theme.objects.all().last()
    return  mytheme in Theme.objects.all()
```

In my templates, I would like to write static path as a dynamic path depends on variable theme selected by user :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% load user_tags %}

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    {% if mytheme == 'Datasystems' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Datasystems/css/Base_Accueil.css' %}"/>
    {% elif mytheme == 'Cameroun' %}
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'Cameroun/css/Base_Accueil.css' %}"/>
    {% endif %}

    etc ....
```

I'm a bit lost. I think that my process could work pretty well but maybe something is not written as a pythonic way or something else.

I tried to be concise and specific.

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`get_static_prefix` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#get-static-prefix) to do this semi-manually:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% get_static_prefix %}{{ mytheme }}/css/Base_Accueil.css"/>
```

Comment: I'm getting a very bad css stylesheet. It means that my template.html file doesn't see the correct staticfiles path. Is it possible that `GetTheme` function in template_tags file are wrong ?

Comment: Well, yes; that code doesn't make much sense at all, and returns a boolean (which is always true, since the theme you have just retrieved will always be in Theme.objects.all()). What exactly are you trying to do there?

Comment: Ok. I have a table which is named `Theme` with two components : `id`, `favorite_theme`. Each time I'm filling the Theme form, I add a row in this table (right up to now). So  in order to get the choosen theme, I'm picking up the last row in the table. In this row, I extract `favorite_theme` which is `Datasystems` or `Cameroun` and this variable have to be in my staticfiles path.

Comment: OK, so why don't you just return `mytheme`? What's the point of that `in` comparison?

Comment: If I just return `mytheme`, I'm getting a template page without css stylesheet in my django website. So I assume that something is wrong or maybe I missed something somewhere. How I could print `href` ? It will be a way to check this ?

Comment: Can you not do View source in your browser?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting this error : `GET 
http://localhost:8000/static//css/Base_Accueil.css`. So he doesn't find `{{mytheme}}`

Comment: I think you should read the documentation on custom template tags; you haven't registered the tag, nor have you done anything to assign the value to a context variable. You need the `assignment_tag` decorator.

Comment: I'm reading docs and I modified my tags.py file like this : `@register.filter
def GetTheme(Theme):
    
    mytheme = Theme.objects.values_list('favorite_theme').last()
    return mytheme`  But still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution based on different answers and I will explain what I've done. This solution works for me with `Django 1.10` and use `context_processors` to do that.

**First step : Modify settings.py file**

I modified my settings.py file and more precisely `TEMPLATES PART`. For the moment, this modification is just for Accueil Application but I will extend this process to all applications :

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug' : DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'myapp.context_processors.context_processors_name_function'],
        },
    },
]
```

With the following example, the last line will be written like this :

```
# 'myapp.context_processors.context_processors_name_function'
'Accueil.context_processors.GetTheme'
```

**Second step : Create context_processors.py file in my application**

I created this new file in my application part. As above, it will be extend to others applications :

```
from django.conf import settings
from Configurations.models import Theme

def GetTheme(request):
    return {'mytheme' : Theme.objects.values_list('favorite_theme').last()[0].encode("ascii")}
```

**Third step : Modify my Base.html for Accueil application**

I have a base template which manage my Accueil application. I have to write header like this is I want to take account the context_processors variable :

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% get_static_prefix %}{{ mytheme }}/css/Base_Accueil.css"/>
```

Through this way, I can pick up the last row from my `Theme` table and put the variable in `{{ mytheme }}`. Then, I created my good theme url. Now, Django will search all css file in the good repository.

From now, when I fill the formulary with a choice between two themes : Datasystems and Cameroun and validate my choice, the new theme is taken account and the global background-color change due to my theme choice !

Hopfully my answer will help others programmers !

Thank you for all :)