# Displaying variable from tags file or context_processors in Django Template

Tags: python, html, django

According to my other question about : [Handle dynamic staticfiles path with Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393309/handle-dynamic-staticfiles-path-with-django/42393578?noredirect=1#comment71937345_42393578)

I am not finding the way to solve my problem. I would like to insert in my HTML template a variable corresponding to a Django query.

I already used tags in order to allow some parts depending on users' groups.

My tags.py file looks like :

```
from django import template
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group 
from Configurations.models import Theme

register = template.Library() 

@register.filter(name='has_group') 
def has_group(user, group_name):
    group =  Group.objects.get(name=group_name) 
    return group in user.groups.all() 

@register.assignment_tag
def GetTheme(Theme):

    mytheme = Theme.objects.values_list('favorite_theme').last()
    return mytheme
```

And my HTML template looks like :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    {% load staticfiles %}
    {% load static %}
    {% load user_tags %}

    <title> DatasystemsEC - Accueil </title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% get_static_prefix %}{{ mytheme }}/css/Base_Accueil.css"/>
```

The goal is to pick up the variable `mytheme` in my tags.py file and insert it in my html template.

In return, I'm getting all the time :

```
#Look double // in my url
http://localhost:8000/static//css/Base_Accueil.html

#I should get 
http://localhost:8000/static/{{ mytheme }}/css/Base_Accueil.html
```

But, after a long moment to search a solution and with the generosity from @DanielRoseman in my previous post, I don't find the solution.

Maybe someone had indices or ideas ?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry if it is silly question, but instead of doing custom tag why don't you just add `mytheme` to the template context in view? Something like this `context['mytheme']=Theme.objects.values_list('favorite_theme').last()`. Also if every user has his own theme shouldn't you filter Theme only for current user: ` Theme.objects.filter(user=request.user).values_list('favorite_theme').last()`

Comment: It's not at all a silly question ! The theme have to be applied everywhere in my django website. The selected theme change background-color, ... on all html template pages. Only admin (that's to say me) can change the theme just by checking a RadioSelectBox. If I put `mytheme` in view, I have to make this in all views (about 10 applications) and for each function right ? That's why tags file seems a better idea but I can make an error ^^

Comment: Well, try to fix couple of things. First of all remove argument from `GetTheme` to avoid overriding of `Theme` name: `def GetTheme():`. Secondly assign `mytheme` variable in template: `{% GetTheme as mytheme %}` before using it.

Comment: I'm getting  `Invalid block tag on line 8: 'GetTheme'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?` for `{% GetTheme as mytheme %}`

Comment: Probably you did not load tag.py you need do this `{% load tags %}` where  `tags` is the name of module file. Also you need to restart server after adding new template tag.

Comment: `{% load user_tags %}` corresponds to user_tags.py file. So the file is loaded correctly in my template. I'm not working on a server but on my laptop (localhost).

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution based on different answers and I will explain what I've done. This solution works for me with `Django 1.10` :

**First step : Modify settings.py file**

I modified my settings.py file and more precisely `TEMPLATES PART`. For the moment, this modification is just for Accueil Application but I will extend this process to all applications :

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'debug' : DEBUG,
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'myapp.context_processors.context_processors_name_function'],
        },
    },
]
```

With the following example, the last line will be written like this :

```
# 'myapp.context_processors.context_processors_name_function'
'Accueil.context_processors.GetTheme'
```

**Second step : Create context_processors.py file in my application**

I created this new file in my application part. As above, it will be extend to others applications :

```
from django.conf import settings
from Configurations.models import Theme

def GetTheme(request):
    return {'mytheme' : Theme.objects.values_list('favorite_theme').last()[0].encode("ascii")}
```

**Third step : Modify my Base.html for Accueil application**

I have a base template which manage my Accueil application. I have to write header like this is I want to take account the context_processors variable :

```
 {% load static %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% get_static_prefix %}{{ mytheme }}/css/Base_Accueil.css"/>
```

Through this way, I can pick up the last row from my `Theme` table and put the variable in `{{ mytheme }}`. Then, I created my good theme url. Now, Django will search all css file in the good repository.

From now, when I fill the formulary with a choice between two themes : Datasystems and Cameroun and validate my choice, the new theme is taken account and the global background-color change due to my theme choice !

Hopfully my answer will help others programmers !

Thank you for all :)

Answer (score 1):

you can write custom `context_processors`.

## settings.py

```
TEMPLATES = [
   {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'web', 'templates'),],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.core.context_processors.media',
            'django.core.context_processors.static',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'myapp.contextprocessor.mytheme',
        ],
    },
  },
]
```

## contextprocessor.py

```
def mytheme(request):
   return {'mytheme': 'red'}
```

Comment: I followed your example and this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32828536/django-no-module-named-context-processors-error-after-reboot. But CSS stylesheet doesn't appear ..

Comment: Does `{{mytheme}}` print on template as `red`?

Comment: I found the solution based on your answer and some docs. I will write a whole answer to do that ;) Thank you